# Two Column A & B, Table Y (A, B) are referred to Table X (A, B). When A in Y is changed, how to make B in Y change to referred Table X value?

Tags: postgresql

I am working on a WPF program. In this program, I have two `DataGrid`, one is `Quotation List` and another is a `Quotation Status List`. Both the `Quotation List`'s data and `Quotation Status List`'s data are stored in the **PostgreSQL** database's table (**quotation_list** & **quotation_status_list**).

In **quotation_list** Table, there will be two columns named `status` and `status_color`. The `status` is used to present the ***status*** of the quotation and the `status_color` is used to control the the row's **Foreground** via **Binding** method in `WPF` `TextBox` Control.

```
<DataGridTemplateColumn SortMemberPath="status" CanUserSort="True" Header="Status" Width="100" >
    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBox Name="Box_status" Foreground="{Binding status_color}" Text="{Binding status}" IsReadOnly="True" />
        </DataTemplate>
    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
</DataGridTemplateColumn>

<DataGridTemplateColumn SortMemberPath="status_color" CanUserSort="True" Header="Color" Width="100" >
    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBox Name="Box_status_color" Foreground="{Binding status_color}" Text="{Binding status_color}" IsReadOnly="True" />
        </DataTemplate>
    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
</DataGridTemplateColumn>
```

**What I want to achieve are:**

1. When user edit the `status_color` in **quotation_status_list** Table, all the `status_color` in the **quotation_list** with that `status_color` will be changed.

**quotation_status_list**

```
 id |  status  | status_color 
----+----------+--------------
  1 |  Active  |     Red      
  2 |  Firm    |     Blue
```

**quotation_list**

```
 id |  status  | status_color |  title 
----+----------+--------------+--------
  1 |  Active  |     Red      |   abc       
  2 |  Firm    |     Blue     |   def    
  3 |  Active  |     Red      |   hij
```

After modify the `status_color` **Red** to **Black**, the `status_color` value in `quotation_list` will change automatically.

**quotation_status_list**

```
 id |  status  | status_color 
----+----------+--------------
  1 |  Active  |     Black    
  2 |  Firm    |     Blue
```

**quotation_list**

```
 id |  status  | status_color |  title 
----+----------+--------------+--------
  1 |  Active  |     Black    |   abc       
  2 |  Firm    |     Blue     |   def   
  3 |  Active  |     Black    |   hij
```

2. When user edit the `status` in **quotation_list** Table, its `status_color` value will be changed to `status_color` in **quotation_status_list** Table.

**quotation_status_list**

```
 id |  status  | status_color 
----+----------+--------------
  1 |  Active  |     Red      
  2 |  Firm    |     Blue
```

**quotation_list**

```
 id |  status  | status_color |  title 
----+----------+--------------+--------
  1 |  Active  |     Red      |   abc       
  2 |  Firm    |     Blue     |   def   
  3 |  Active  |     Red      |   hij
```

After modify, the `status` of row 1 is changed to **Firm**, the `status_color` will be changed to **Blue** automatically.

**quotation_status_list**

```
 id |  status  | status_color 
----+----------+--------------
  1 |  Active  |     Red      
  2 |  Firm    |     Blue
```

**quotation_list**

```
 id |  status  | status_color |  title 
----+----------+--------------+--------
  1 |  Firm    |     Blue     |   abc       
  2 |  Firm    |     Blue     |   def    
  3 |  Active  |     Red      |   hij
```

To achieve these two function, I try to create two Table by

**quotation_status_list**

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS quotation_status_list
( 
    id SERIAL UNIQUE NOT NULL, 
    status TEXT UNIQUE NOT NULL, 
    status_color TEXT UNIQUE NOT NULL, 
    PRIMARY KEY(id, status, status_color)
);
```

**quotation_list**

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS quotation_list
( 
    id SERIAL UNIQUE NOT NULL, 
    title TEXT NOT NULL, 
    status TEXT NOT NULL, 
    status_color TEXT NOT NULL, 
    FOREIGN KEY(status, status_color)  
    REFERENCES quotation_status_list(status, status_color)  
    ON DELETE NO ACTION  
    ON UPDATE CASCADE
) ;
```

I can create the **quotation_status_list** Table but I cannot create the **quotation_list**.
The error is

```
there is no unique constraint matching given keys for referenced table "quotation_status_list"
```

What will be the problem, the `status`, `status_color` in **quotation_status_list** should be **UNIQUE** and they are **PRIMARY KEY**.
Do I use wrong method? or Database cannot do this job?

Any suggestion are welcome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do not need a 3-column PK in quotation_status_list, the single column is sufficient. Then *Do not* repeat `status` and `status_color` quotation_list. Remove them and add the column containing the PK of quotation_status_list.

```
create table quotation_status_list(
       id           integer generated always as identity  primary key
     , status       text unique not null 
     , status_color text unique not null 
     );


create table if not exists quotation_list(     
       id                  integer generated always as identity 
     , title               text not null  
     , quotation_status_id integer
                           references quotation_status_list(id)
                           on delete no action  
     ) ;
```

Now to retrieve the status and status_color join the tables:

```
select ql.title
     , qs.status
     , gs.status_color 
  from quotation_list        ql  
  join quotation_status_list qs 
    on (qs.id  = ql.quotation_status_id);
```

Now any change (except PK, which should **never** be changed) in quotation_status_list is automatically reflected in the select.  

Note: I used the newer preferred `generated as identity` for the keys. If you have an older Postgres version which does not support (prior to v10?) serial accomplishes the same.

Comment: Thank for your reply. If I use "generated as identity", do it mean that I don't need to create the "sequence" column anymore as they do the same job of auto add value?

Comment: Correct, you do not create a a sequence. Postgres will create and use a sequence, but you do not actually deal with it.